# How to get firefox select search engine with flag like chrome does

Tags: firefox

In Chrome browser, there is the possibility to define flags for selecting a specific search engine, depending on what you want to use for a current search. In your address bar, you can type for example

`w my search term`

By typing the `w` + `space`, chrome selects Wikipedia as search engine for "my search term". (Of course, having configured that `w` means Wikipedia.)

Is there a way to get this behaviour in Firefox, too?

To avoid misunderstandings: I know how to set a default search engine in Firefox, but I want to select it ... let's say ... 'dynamically', without the detour via calling the search engine's webpage before and typing in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Preferences` -> `Search` -> `Search Shortcuts` you can specify a keyword, `w` in your example.

If you want to add more wikipedia languages, go to wikipedia in that language, search form something and in the results page (doesn't work if it directly redirects to the article) click the `...` in the address bar. You should see an `Add Search Engine` option.

Comment: No problem. Please, consider marking answer as correct.